# How can I use CQL in WFS layers in openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I've tried a lot of times to use the OpenLayers CQL example but nothing changes. Is there any way to use CQL or filter.

Comment: which example are you trying to use? what goes wrong?

Comment: Are you using Geoserver? CQL filters don't work with any other WMS service.

Comment: Yes i m using geoserver  and  [link](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cql-format.html) Also i ve tried to many times .

Comment: works for me - what is your actual problem

Comment: share your code for people to look at where you might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have CQL in example:

```
STATE_ABBR >= 'B' AND STATE_ABBR <= 'O'
```

Try to change B to A and you will see change

```
STATE_ABBR >= 'A' AND STATE_ABBR <= 'O'
```

BTW
OpenLayers supports less function then GeoServer but you can read
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code:

```
lyr = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(yourLayerName, yourLayerService,{
      'VERSION' : '1.1.0',
      'layers' : yourLayerNum,
      format: 'image/png',
      transparent: true,
      CQL_FILTER: "STATE_ABBR >= 'B' AND STATE_ABBR <= 'O'"

},
      isBaseLayer: false
);

map.addLayer(lyr);
```

dont forget **VERSION** is important for getting true result.

i hope it helps you...